# Access storage account using SAS in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, shared-access-signatures

I do not have access to a storage account. I am provided only with SAS token at container level. Need to upload a file(create a blob within the container) to the storage account as blob in terraform.

This is my below code. Where to use the SAS token inorder to create a blob within the container.

```
data "azurerm_storage_account" "eg" {
  name                = "abc"
  resource_group_name = "xyz-rg"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "test" {
  name                   = "${local.currentdate}_${var.filename}"
  storage_account_name   = data.azurerm_storage_account.eg.name
  storage_container_name = "ctr"
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = "./myfile.txt"
}
```

If my storage account is in another subscription will they following block of code work. I am getting **ResourceNotFound** error.

```
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "test" {
  provider               = azurerm.aabbxx
  name                   = "${local.currentdate}_${var.filename}"
  storage_account_name   = "mystacc"
  storage_container_name = "ctr"
  type                   = "Block"

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az storage blob upload --account-name mystacc -f ./myFile.csv -c ctr -n MyBlob --sas-token {SAS-token}"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple answer: if you do not have access to the storage account resource, you will not be able to manage/create the blob like that. You could use a local-exec with azure CLI

Something like this

```
resource "foo" "bar" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az storage blob upload -f /path/to/file -c mycontainer -n MyBlob --sas-token {MY-SAS}"
  }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-upload

Comment: I have added a new resource block. Please help me resolve the error ResourceNotFound error. @silent

Comment: Google on the exact usage of the local exec together with null resources

Comment: Provider cannot be used in null resource block. That's why need to use the above resource block

Comment: Did you manage to fix this @user2120 I'm getting the same error, but I'm in the same sub. Did silent solution help? His answer is a little vague to go on.